# Set variable from exe output using batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I want to check Edge webdriver version using batch file. The name of the webdriver is `msedgedriver.exe` and I can check the version using this command manually.

```
msedgedriver.exe -v
```

And the output is

```
MSEdgeDriver 96.0.1054.62 (f97cb2ce0103f6eaa6dc1994d77748c659744916)
```

But when I use batch for to get the output, it shows nothing.
The batch code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN ('msedgedriver.exe -v') DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%
```

I've tried every answer in [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file) link.
I've checked the file path and it's correct.
and tried `'call "msedgedriver.exe -v"'` or `'msedgedriver.exe /v'` or every other combination.

Comment: Are you running the batch from within the same folder as of where msedgedriver.exe is located? Otherwise you would have to provide the full path to msedgedriver.exe

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that, I've tried the full path and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the location for testing I didn't find it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand exactly about > provide the location.
this is the full path "C:\Users\alient\Documents\Pycharm Projects\bot_onnx\msedgedriver.exe" and this the bat file path "C:\Users\alient\Documents\Pycharm Projects\bot_onnx\check_version.bat"

Comment: Ah ok, I figured out this is not included by default in Windows...

Comment: This is the [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) to download `msedgedriver.exe`

Comment: What do you want to save in %Var% the whole line or just 96.0.1054.62 ?

Comment: I just want to save second output (version). I've tried "tokens=* skip=1" and when I saw it doesn't work I tried other flags in Stack Overflow answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that because the output has parentesis "()" you would have to use some extra quotes:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%F IN ('"msedgedriver.exe -v"') DO SET var=%%F

echo %var%
pause
```